# How to point external domain to VPS server

Tags: dns, hosting, vps, nameservers, bluehost

I have a Bluehost VPS account and I need to point my external domain which is purchased from porkbun to my VPS server. After some research, I have changed the A record in the domain registrar to my VPS server IP and changed name servers to Bluehost servers(which are ns1.bluehost.com and ns2.bluehost.com). Currently, when accessing the domain I'm seeing the default Bluehost page, but it does not seem to be connected with the server as it does not display any file I'm updating in the root folder. Is there any step I'm missing? I have tried changing nameservers of the VPS server itself by editing DNS settings in the domain, but any of them does not seem to be working. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to 'browse' to your VPS server then you would need to add an 'A' record type into the DNS for the domain name.
For example, if you are browsing to 'test.mydomain.com' and your VPS IP Address is '192.186.1.15' then you should add an A Record into the domain zone file with the following detals:

Host Record - test

Points To - 192.168.1.15

These details are taken from the following page:

https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/dns-management-add-edit-or-delete-dns-entries#add